# Which class is super class of all classes

Tags: java, android

I am a Java beginner. I am little bit confused as to which is the **Super class of all classes** in Java?

Comment: sorry for bad English

Comment: An all Android documentation class documentation pages, the class inheritance hierarchy is shown and is clickable.

Comment: ok.... I m confuse for that Throwable=The superclass of all classes which can be thrown by the VM. Object=The root class of the Java class hierarchy.

Comment: Ok... Thanks to all experts..

Comment: No confusion.  Everything inherits from `Object`.  Only throwable exceptions inherit from `Throwable`.  All men are humnans.  Not all humans are men.  `Object=The superclass of all classes which can be thrown by the VM` is strictly also true, but is a useless statement since it is not exclusive, e.g. `TextView` inherits from `Object` but is not throwable.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the [`Object`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object.html) documentation:

> The root class of the Java class hierarchy. All non-primitive types (including arrays) inherit either directly or indirectly from this class.

Answer (score 4):

I believe it's java.lang.Object

Answer (score 4):

java.lang.Object class is the super class for all java classes.
you can see with following example:

```
   class test
   {
    public static void main(String a[]){
     System.out.println("hi this java");
    }
   }
```

save program with- test.java
compile program using - javac test.java

now type following cmd to see real output ;
javap test

- **output**--

  ```
  class test extends java.lang.Object{
   test();
   public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  }
  ```

the first line itself tells that by default it extends java.lang.Object.

Answer (score 3):

**java.lang.Object** is a super class of any class by default. 
Also **Object** class is a superclass for all **interfaces** by default, Ex

```
public interface ICommand
{

}

class Test {
   ICommand c;
   Object o = c;  //works fine
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Object` is the super class of all other classes you use, including the ones you implemented.

And you'll see the following methods are inherited from `Object` in every class.

- equals(Object o)
- getClass()
- hashCode()
- notify()
- notifyAll()
- toString()
- wait()
- wait(long millis, int nanos)
- wait(long millis)

You may find [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object.html) useful

Answer (score 1):

The Object class is the super class of all classes.
Same as Java

Answer (score 1):

Object class is the superclass.

Reference: Android documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object.html

> The root class of the Java class hierarchy. All non-primitive types (including arrays) inherit either directly or indirectly from this class.

Answer (score 1):

as people already said, Object is the class everyone inherit from.
and fyi, u can also overrid methods like "toString()", "equals()" to suit your personal new Class needs.

[this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) is a nice tutorial for starting.

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.Object

it is The root class of the Java class hierarchy. All non-primitive types (including arrays) inherit either directly or indirectly from this class. more info at : http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object.html

Answer (score -1):

Object Class is the Base class or Super Class of all Classes.
Its a Class not an Instance of an Object.
Its the Biggest Class in java